# How do I expand a notification bubble using the keyboard without Super + N shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, notification, statusbar

Assuming my desktop environment is different than GNOME and that I do not have the predefined <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> keyboard shortcut that comes with it, how may I expand a prompted notification bubble using the keyboard and without using the mouse?

Is it possible to create a custom keyboard shortcut to do this?

Comment: I think that this is related somehow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KMqvAq6WYY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not always natively supported, we can always make a tweak of our own and we'll create it in **two parts**:

1. Create a desktop environment mouse action automation (essentially control your mouse actions using commands).
   This can be done using the `xdotool`, which needs to be installed first using this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y xdotool
   ```
2. Create a custom keyboard shortcut that executes a command in Ubuntu.

   - If you're not familiar with this feature, [this Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) will show you how to create a shortcut in GNOME.
   - For Xubuntu users [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90513/how-do-i-change-my-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xubuntu) & for Ubuntu Mate users [this documentation](https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/#page-shortcuts) will show you how to create shortcuts in the respective desktop environments.

### Using `xdotool` to move your mouse position to a specific location on screen:

Sending the `xdotool` a `mousemove` command argument, followed by our desired location will cause the mouse position to move onto that point on screen:

```
xdotool mousemove X Y
```

where `X` is your horizontal position, and `Y` is your vertical position. The trick is to find where your notification appears, and choose a location that is inside the notification popup. Usually, `1000 70` is the default location, but that depends on your resolution and system settings.

### How may I determine exactly where my notification appears?

You may use the `notify-send` command to invoke a notification!
The first argument would be the title, while the second argument is the body:

```
notify-send "my_title" "my_message"
```

Once the notification is gone, place a file or a folder in the middle of where it was, and start experimenting the `xdotool` command.
Whenever you're pointing over that file it will be highlighted, just as if you were hovering your mouse over it manually!

### Final step - imitating a mouse hover on the notification so it expands:

If you've reached this part, you've probably noticed that the notification did not expand. That is because we also need to move our mouse a little on top of it to imitate a user's behavior of expanding it.

The solution? just use another `xdotool mousemove` command right after the first one was executed **within the range** of your notification pop up. For example:

```
xdotool mousemove 1000 70 && xdotool mousemove 900 70
```

If you see the result suites you, **copy the working command** and create a **keyboard shortcut** just as described in the link at the top of this answer.

Enjoy your new tweak!