# Ubuntu MATE 21.04: Keyboard shortcut to show notifications list

Tags: shortcut-keys, notification, ubuntu-mate, 21.04, ayatana

I'm trying to find keyboard shortcuts to:

(1) Show notifications list

(2) Clear notifications list

I have gone through this AskUbuntu thread:

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325785/create-a-custom-keyboard-key-for-opening-the-latest-notification
```

and Ubuntu desktop guide:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-notifications.html.en
```

but none of 'em working for Ubuntu **MATE** 21.04... because when I open the `Menu` > `Keyboard Shortcuts`, there are no entries for anything related to notifications. Also, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> does nothing.

I can't find any option to view or create keyboard shortcuts in Ayatana indicators settings either.

So, how do I create custom keyboard shortcuts to show and clear notifications list? Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu MATE 21.04

Indicator applet complete: 1.24.0

Ayatana indicators settings: 21.1.28-1

Ayatana indicator notifications: 0.8.90-1

Comment: Check https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/ and/or ask also on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: @n0rbert Thanks, gone through the guide you've mentioned but couldn't find anything that would help me. Also, posted the question at Ubuntu MATE community: `https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/keyboard-shortcut-to-show-notifications-list-in-ubuntu-mate-21-04/24213`